# How Can I Use Breeze with Select2 4?

Tags: breeze, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

How can I use Breeze to load remote data in the [Select2 jQuery plugin](https://select2.github.io/)? The [built in ajax functionality uses jQuery](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) but the documentation [specifies that you can use the ajax property to setup your own remote data sources](https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax). What would be the best way to use breeze with the ajax property?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with what I think is a good solution. This example would run against the [Todo Server](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/todo-server) in Breeze's Todo samples (e.g. [Todo-Angular Sample](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/todo-angular)).

My solution utilizes the data function to create the query, connects Breeze's then and failure functions to select2's success and failure functions, and has full paging functionality using Breeze's [take and skip](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#Paging).

```js
//Setting for the number of items to get per request
var numberPerPage = 10;

jQuery('select').select2({
    //Custom ajax method that uses breeze to get the results
    ajax: {
        transport: function (params, success, failure) {
            manager.executeQuery(params.data).then(function (data) {
                success(data.results);
            }).fail(function (data) {
                failure();
            });
            return { abort: function () { } };//Return a dummy abort function since select2 requires one but Breeze doesn't have that functionality
        },
        data: function (params) {
            var query = {
                from: 'Todos',
                orderBy: ['Description'],
                where: {
                    or: [
                        { 'Description': { 'Contains': params.term } },
                    ]
                },
                take: numberPerPage,
                skip: (numberPerPage * ((params.page || 1) - 1))
            };
            return new breeze.EntityQuery(query);//Return a Breeze query as the data, which we'll request in the transport
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            return {
                //Convert the returned objects into select2 friendly objects
                results: jQuery.map(data, function (val) {
                    return {
                        id: this.Id,
                        text: this.Description
                    };
                }),
                pagination: {//Must return this to get paging to work
                    more: data.length == numberPerPage//If the data returned a total page, we should try again for more
                }
            };
        },
    }
});
```